# Determining whether a digraph has a sink

Tags: algorithms

Let $G= (V,E)$ be a directed graph with $n$ vertices.
A sink is a vertex $s\in V$ such that for all $ v \in V$, $(v,s) \notin E$.  Devise an algorithm that, given the adjacency matrix of $G$, determines whether or not $G$ has a sink in time $O(n)$.

Does this pseudocode code look good?

```
# Input: An adjacency matrix G

# Output: True if G has a sink and False if G does not have a sink.

Algorithm DetermineSink(G)
i←0
j←0
for 0 to len(G)
   if G[i,j] = 1 ∧ j ≠ i # if there is an edge emanating from i, it is not a sink.
    
     return False
   if G[j,i] = 0 ∧ j ≠ i # there exists no edge and hence it is not a sink
     
     return False
return True
```

Comment: What does "for 0 to len(G)" do? How are $i,j$ updated?

Comment: A simple adversary argument shows that given an adjacency matrix, you need to look at *all* entries in order to determine whether there is a sink or not. The adversary simply answers $A[i,j] = 0$ to all queries, unless the query is the last one in its row, in which case it answers $A[i,j] = 1$.

Comment: Yes I know that but I dont know how to change my code to check all the rows if they are zero when you get the 1 in any one column.

Comment: If there is a sink,the adjacency matrix will contain all 1's except diagnol in one column and all 0's(except diagnol)in the corresponding row of the vertex.

Comment: The argument implies that any valid algorithm would take $\Omega(n^2)$ time.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the definition of a sink correctly. It is a vertex with no outgoing edges.

Comment: Yes I get that.It means that if Matrix[i][j]=0 and matrix[j][i]=1 then there exist a sink.

Comment: I don't see why. If your digraph is an oriented cycle, then there is no sink.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.